# AngujarJS template not rendering correct

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a problem with getting a template populated with data, from a directive.

This is what I have:

```
app.directive('mypopover', function ($compile,$templateCache) {

        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var popOverContent;

                popOverContent = $templateCache.get('personPopOverTemplate.html');                  

                var options = {
                    content: popOverContent,
                    placement: "right",
                    html: true,
                    date: scope.date
                };
                $(element).popover(options);

                $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            }
        };
    });

<script type="text/ng-template" id="personPopOverTemplate.html">
    <div><b>Navn:</b>{{scope.row.entity.Navn}}</div>
    <div><b>Email:</b>{{scope.row.entity.Email}}</div>
    <div><b>Ansættelsessted:</b> {{scope.row.entity.Ansaettelsessted}}</div>
</script>
```

The problem is, that what this ends up showing is

**Navn:**{{scope.roe.entity.Navn}}

**Email:**{{scope.row.entity.Email}}

**Ansættelsessted:**{{scope.row.entity.Ansaettelsessted}}

I can't figure out why its not rendering the correct data.
If i pause in the directive and from the console try and access scope.row.entity.Navn is has a value.

But this is not shown in the template. Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but try to compile the popOverContent directly: $compile(popOverContent)(scope);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you need to compile your template, not the element, but you need to do it before you assign it to the options after you get it with the `$templateCache`.

Example:

```
app.directive('mypopover', function($compile, $templateCache) {
   return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         var popOverContent, options;
         popOverContent = $compile($templateCache.get('personPopOverTemplate.html'))(scope);

         options = {
            html: true,
            trigger: 'hover',
            content: popOverContent,
            placement: "bottom"
         };

         $(element).popover(options);
      }
   };
});
```

<kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wHsQ1vzXAXY2NOSbN4Fs?p=preview)</kbd>

Also, to have the HTML render properly I had to remove all of the spaces you had in your tags as well as the `scope` declaration in your binding:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="personPopOverTemplate.html">
      <div><b> Navn: </b>{{row.Navn}}</div> <div> <b> Email: </b>{{row.Email}}</div> <div> <b> Ansæ ttelsessted: </b> {{row.Ansaettelsessted}}</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure as your code does not include the part where you set your scope variables, but try it with this view:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="personPopOverTemplate.html">
    <div><b>Navn:</b>{{row.entity.Navn}}</div>
    <div><b>Email:</b>{{row.entity.Email}}</div>
    <div><b>Ansættelsessted:</b> {{row.entity.Ansaettelsessted}}</div>
</script>
```

You do not need to use your `scope` object inside the template. When angular parses your template it will interprete each variable you use as a property of `scope`. Thus, when you use  `{{scope.row.entity.Name}}` in your template, it will look for a variable: `scope.scope.row.entity.Name`